# Html/CSS floating problems

Tags: html, css

I'm having some problems with my css, my 2 div's are getting under eachother. I want them both next to eachother.

I'm having a body with a user menu and content div's inside.

HTML:

```
<div id="body">
            <div id="user-menu">
                @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                { 
                    <ul id="account-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("My profile", "MyProfile", "Profile")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Links", "Links", "Profile")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("History", "History", "Profile")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Credits", "Credits", "Profile")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Settings", "Manage", "Account")</li>
                    </ul>  
                }
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Immo QR by eNetricity.com</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#body 
{

margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 960px;

}

#user-menu 
{
float: left;
width: 15%;

}

#content 
{
float: right;
width: 85%;

}
```

Image:

Greets

Comment: Float them both left and give them a dimension in pixels.

Comment: You have one too many `</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathias, 
you have closed a div unnecessarily, please remove that.
also give float left to both div.

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind which should help fix the problem:

1. Since the right-floating `<div>` comes after the left-floating `<div>` it may be moving to the next line prior to floating. Try floating both elements left.
2. Sometimes browsers round **up** to the nearest pixel when calculating sizes. Does your code work better with a 10/90 split? 20/80? If your full container is 960px, try calculating the column sizes manually in pixels.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting border: 0 on both the floated elements because unless you're resetting your CSS via a reset or normalise, they will inherit a nominal border:

```
#body 
{
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 960px;
}

#user-menu 
{
float: left;
width: 15%;
}

#content 
{
float: right;
width: 85%;
}

#content, #user-menu{
```

border: 0;
    }

```
#footer{
  clear: both;

}
```

Heres a codepen:[1](http://cdpn.io/pJChy):

HTH